# load flex application in flex mobile application

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile-application, swfloader

I want to load a flex application in mobile flex application and also i want it to interact with the parent application.
Right now I am trying to load the swf with swfLoader in mobile app, but it gives me security error.
And also should I want the parent application to be generic in terms of child application...as in down the line if someone wants he can have another child application with same name run.

This is in the main application:

```
    private function connectHandler(event:Event):void {
      NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeys, false, 0, true);
      mySWFLoader.source="file:///sdcard/Galaxy/Teacher/Shell.swf";
      mySWFLoader.visible = true; 
      mySWFLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,swfLoaderHandler);
    }
```

Comment: I see your question is tagged as Android and, for that platform, it may be possible. Keep in mind that for iOS this is absolutely not doable.

Comment: Yes I intend to do it for android. But can you please help me decipher this. What do I do so that I dont get security issues..
P.S. are you from alicante..?

Comment: Unfortunately, my experience is with iOS, so I can't help. I was just saying in case you want to migrate to iOS later, to avoid you headaches. P.S.: I'm not from Alicante, 1/2 Andalucía, 1/2 Asturias.

Comment: You might be able to get more help if you specify which error you are getting and maybe paste a snippet of code too.

Comment: This is in the main application:  
    private function connectHandler(event:Event):void {
            NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(
         KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,     handleKeys, false, 0, true);
            mySWFLoader.source="file:///sdcard/Galaxy/Teacher/Shell.swf";
        mySWFLoader.visible = true;
            mySWFLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,swfLoaderHandler);
   }

Comment: And in child application I use url loader to load an xml. There I get an error. So the question here is the external swf is not allowed to load an resources?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#allowDomain%28%29) should help.

The idea to create a "portal-like" service with:

- a shell that is not prone to changes
- several sub applications that you can load into it and compile separately

It's, well, tempting - but, from my personal experience, there is a lot of trouble with doing this, especially if you're doing **Flex** on a **mobile** with **sub-applications**...

Comment: Thanks buddy..great help. Can you elaborate the problems I can bump into while developing this for mobile..?

Comment: i guess you're being a bit ironic (about great help) O-)
The portal-like service i had been working on was not intended to be run on a mobile device, so i can't say much in this respect. I can not recall all the hurdles i had, but something that i remember - class declaration collisions (fixed in player 10.3) and trouble mixing http and https amf-services in any 1 application.

Your main concerns would probably be: performance, freeing up memory/garbage collection (properly loading and unloading applications)/memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load an external swf like that.

Import Shell.swf file into your `src` source folder inside flex mobile project.

then read using the below script

```
private function connectHandler(event:Event):void {
  NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeys, false, 0, true);
  mySWFLoader.source="Shell.swf";
  mySWFLoader.visible = true; 
  mySWFLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,swfLoaderHandler);
}
```